# Simple Login System using java

Tags: java, authentication

Im trying to get the program to look through the usernames array to check for a match, and then the passwords array to check for a match in the same index as the first match. The usernames loop is only working when the first username is inputted, and the passwords loop wont work at all. This is what I've got so far:

```
boolean found;
        for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
            found= true;
            do{
                if(usernames[i].equals(Iuser)){
                    System.out.println("Username recognised.");
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Username Incorrect. Try again.");
                    Iuser = Keyboard.readString();
                    found = false;
                }
            }while(found = true);

            System.out.println("Enter your password.");
            String Ipass = Keyboard.readString();
            found = true;
            do{

                if(passwords[i].equals(Ipass)){
                    System.out.println("Access Granted");
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Password Incorrect. Try again.");
                    Ipass = Keyboard.readString();
                    found = false;
                }
            }while(found = true);
```

Comment: `while (found = true);` looks wrong since it is an assignment.

Comment: Not quite related, but I would recommend hashing the passwords in the array and then hashing the user input. If they are equal, then you know that the user has the right password.

Comment: ``found`` isn't changed inside the while loop, so you might as well say while(true)

Answer (score 0):

```
        boolean foundUser = false;
    boolean foundPassword = false;
    while (!foundUser) {
        Iuser = Keyboard.readString();
        for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
            if (usernames[i].equals(Iuser)) {
                System.out.println("Username recognised.");
                foundUser = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Username Incorrect. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    while (!foundPassword) {
        System.out.println("Enter your password.");
        String Ipass = Keyboard.readString();
        for (int i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
            if (passwords[i].equals(Ipass)) {
                System.out.println("Access Granted");
                foundPassword = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Password Incorrect. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
```